# Why did Ibrahim greet his father with the Salam, if one shouldn't greet disbelievers with salaam?

Tags: sunnah, greetings, fatwa-explanation, islamqa

It happens that I am told [not to greet disbelievers with Salaam](http://islamqa.info/en/6583), or peace.

However in the [Quran Surah Maryam](http://quran.com/19/47), Ibrahim clearly said peace to his father who at the time was a disbeliever, a polytheist.

I wonder why is this?

I'd appreciate references to Quran and Sunnah.

Comment: The Fatwa you posted says you can't initiate salam, but you have to respond with the same/better greeting. Is your question about initiating the salam? The way it is now makes it look both ways.

Comment: @AmericanMuslim this is about imitating the salaam

Comment: See also: "[“As-Salāmu `Alaykum” for non-Muslims?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1827/9123)". A thing to note is, in your [hadith](http://sunnah.com/muslim/39/16), there is nothing mentioned about polytheists, while Ibrahim's (pbuh) dad was one.

Comment: FWIW, many words in Arabic are homonym.  *اب* can have another meaning here as [here](https://quran.com/2/133) which while Ismael is the **uncle** of Jacob he referred to using *اب* and also that it doesn't support the idea that the Prophet was born from all-theist parents.

Comment: @Honey What is an all-theist?

Comment: @G.Bach all theist (muwahhid) as NOT being a *mushrik/kafir*

Comment: @Honey Do you mean "monotheist"?

Comment: @G.Bach my bad. I meant the notion that ALL the parents of the prophets were monotheists. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @G.Bach I just learned this: from [this](https://quran.com/6/74) verse. Ibrahim is speaking to someone and is saying **your** people. It's not common for someone to refer to his father's nation by *your* it would be *our* nation. Likely it's someone who didn't live with him. Like an uncle or a guardian.

Answer (score 2):

> **وَإِذَا سَمِعُوا اللَّغْوَ أَعْرَضُوا عَنْهُ وَقَالُوا لَنَا أَعْمَالُنَا وَلَكُمْ أَعْمَالُكُمْ سَلَامٌ عَلَيْكُمْ لَا نَبْتَغِي الْجَاهِلِينَ**
>
> **And when they hear ill speech, they turn away from it and say, *For us are our deeds, and for you are your deeds. Peace will be upon you;
> we seek not the ignorant.***

I do not think the Fatwa (in the link you provided) is helpful. It does not account for the situation nowadays and I think it does not take into account the circumstances in which Muhammad said those words.

Please refer to this [discussion](http://www.answering-christianity.com/karim/Karim_-_articles_islamic_answers_-_part_2/Greeting_non-Muslims.pdf) in which the circumstances are described. It makes sense. Think about it. Islam is peace and love, not otherwise. If a Muslim does not greet someone, then because he/she has a strong reason to do so. Merely being of another faith is not a strong reason.

Let me summarize:

- The Hadith must be read and understood in its context. It was in a time of hostilities.
- The mentioning of Christians could be due to fuzzy translation. The word Ahl-Al-Kitab is actually being used in Arabic; this can mean *Jews and Christians*, *Christians* or simply *Jews*.
- Some *Jews* were greeting with *Death upon you* which sounds similar to *Peace upon you* in Arabic. It is reasonable to believe that Muhammad simply did not want to stimulate this badness. So simply do not greet that person.

My sincere advice to you:

- Initiate the greeting to anyone in his/her language according the his/her cultural customs. In Arabic we greet in the usual form in Arabic; in English we do likewise in English, etc.
- The greeting in Arabic meaning *I wish you peace* is indeed a noble greeting; not many languages, nations, cultures have this privilege. Use it when you can, but don't exaggerate. Speak the local greeting.
- Don't stimulate bad behaviour. In this case refrain from greeting, but stay polite, keep your heart away from anger.

---

Abraham's (Ibrahim in Arabic) father was a polytheist.

Answer (score 1):

The referred [hadith](http://sunnah.com/muslim/39/16) belongs to a particular stage in the ministry of the Messenger i.e. after *itmam al hujjah*. Tahawi (853-933) [writes](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=379&hid=4810&pid=192313) while explaining a different hadith:

> وَكَانَ فِي الْوَقْتِ الَّذِي أَمَرَهُ اللهُ بِالْعَفْوِ عَنْهُمْ ،
>   وَالصَّفْحِ ، وَتَرْكِ مُجَادَلَتِهِمْ إِلَّا بِالَّتِي هِيَ أَحْسَنُ
>   ، ثُمَّ نَسَخَ اللهُ ذَلِكَ وَأَمَرَهُ بِقِتَالِهِمْ فَنُسِخَ مَعَ
>   ذَلِكَ ، السَّلَامُ عَلَيْهِمْ
>
> There was a time when God ordained the prophet to pardon them, and
>   bear with them (e.g. [5:13](http://tanzil.net/#5:13)) and reason with them in a way that is
>   best ([16:125](http://tanzil.net/#16:125)). Then God annulled this injunction and ordained him
>   to fight them. Therefore, **peace upon them** was revoked alongside.

i.e. after *itmam al hujjah*, the previous injunction was annulled and the fight was carried out as a worldly Divine punishment ([9:14](http://tanzil.net/#9:14)). Greeting people with peace who were subject to Divine punishment would have been absurd. Therefore, the prophet forbade people to do so. Hence, it is not a general directive.

The verse you quoted ([19:47](http://tanzil.net/#19:47)) guides us towards a general attitude that a da`e should follow.

A relevant link: [Greeting Non-Muslims](http://www.renaissance.com.pk/aprq994.html)